# Referencing an Excel Spread Sheet with XML

Tags: excel, xml, powershell, active-directory

Currently I am trying to add users to default groups via Powershell and have been trying to type a script to expedite the process so I do not have to type every single name for each line. (I realize I can also add users to groups via AD and other methods but this is for a large group of users, several hundred or more.)

I currently am trying to use the ADD-ADGroupMember command and am having trouble getting it to reference a CSV file that is converted from an EXCEL SpreadSheet in order to pull the users account names. (the accounts are created using another script that builds each account with a formula heavy Excel sheet)

Currently my code looks like this

```
# Define these as you wish 
$csvPath = "File Path Here"


Import-CSV -Path "$csvpath" | ForEach-Object {

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Group Name Here) -Members $_. "AccountName"    

}
```

But the issue I'm having is I need the members parameter to reference the CSV file but the method used in the other script does not seem to work. 
Any Help would be appreciated and I must apologize due the fact that I am stuck trying to create this without any prior knowledge in coding.

Comment: If your csv file has a header `AccountName` change the line to `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (Group Name Here) -Members $_.AccountName` [See online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps)

Comment: You really need to show us the first two or three lines of your input CSV file, so we can see what headers you are using if any. Sanitize the names and info in there of course.

Comment: So the issue turned out to be an issue with the CSV file and the accounts needing to be created. Thanks for all the help.